# Purposely causing an error fixes my hover over function fabric.js

Tags: javascript

To get my code to work i put in a throw exception error and this makes my javascript work. But this is not the best practice. I have tried a simple 'return' but this does not work to fix my app.

```
    canvas.on('object:over', function(e) {
      var type = e.target.get('type');
          if (type == "Licensed Artwork") {
            e.target.opacity = 0.6;
            e.target.sendToBack();

             throw "";   //purposely throw error fixes my app

          } else if (type == "upload") {        
            e.target.bringToFront();
            canvas.renderAll();
          }     

    });
```

Comment: Can you please describe what happens with, and what happens without the `throw "";` line?

Comment: The app is a html5 canvas using fabric.js. The script above detects when the mouse enters over a canvas object. If I take out the throw then the mouse over only works once. If i put in the throw i can move the mouse over and out of the object and it is detected everytime.